# How to get "Device ID" from Android device under software update settings

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the `Device ID` found under `Settings -> About tablet -> System updates -> Software update settings` under the `Device information` header in Android versions 4.x or 5.x?

Comment: Would that be `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`?

Comment: negative, tried that already :/

Comment: Try this. String device =Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL + " " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " " + Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName(); this will give you just about everything, pull out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong you are looking for your mobile phone's device id which you can get using these line of code

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            deviceId = tm.DeviceId;
```

Also requires the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Also after Android Marshmallow Or API 23 you need to ask for permissions on the fly the code reference for that can be found here:

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: Check android version and request permission if it requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @G.hakim , but additional to that, this API requires `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.So you need to declare the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you want to use this api:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```